# AngularJs Roles Based menu display security concern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I am new to MEAN.js and currently working with application having two roles. User & Admin and I have to display menu based on the use role. for that I have created Header file as below for admin & user role.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" data-ng-if="admin">
         admin menus
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" data-ng-if="user">
         user menus
</ul>
```

where admin & user are controller variables.now I tried different things to set the value of this variables.

1) I have set value for userRole in sessionStorage as below.

```
    $window.sessionStorage.userRole = loggesUser.role (A role from login user)
```

but in this any user can change this value from browser sessionStorage and can see not authorized menus.

2) I have also try to set userRole into cookie as below.

```
  $cookieStore.put('userRole','user')
```

but here user can also change cookie value from browser console by using

```
document.cookie="key=value"
```

so once again un-authorized user can see menus.

3) I also try to put userRole into $scope but user can also change this values from browser console.

so I don't know how can I make my header secure based on roles.can anyone please give me suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user is determined enough there are *numerous* ways a user can modify your user interface and see screens they do not regularly have access to. This is just how it is.

This is resolved by enforcing authorization (not authentication, but you need that too!) on the server. On the server side when a request comes in, check the role of the user before allowing the request to execute. If the user's role does not have the permissions for what they're trying to do, return a 403 response.